# TensorFlow lite conversion: error: op operands must be tensor of 8-bit unsigned integer, but got tensor<1x?x?x3x!tf.quint8>

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to convert a model to TensorFlow Lite after adding a few layers to a model. I have successfully run them with test inputs in Python, and they're working fine. The goal is to allow the model to take in RGB images (uint8), resize and shuffle the channels so that preprocessing is entirely consistent between python and platforms using TensorFlow Lite (avoid using Android bitmap resizing libraries, or embedded system resizing methods). I've found preprocessing to be inconsistent between devices.

It also happens for any other op. This makes me think its the `Input()` layer causing the issue. I'm not sure how to create the layer properly for the conversion to work.

### Model setup code

```py
    input_shape = (None, None, 3) # Im using None here because I want the model to accept arbitrary image sizes.
    input = Input(shape=input_shape, batch_size=1, dtype="uint8")
    bn_axis = 3
    bn_eps = 0.0001

    x = ChannelReversal()(input) # A custom layer
    x = Resizing(224, 224, interpolation='bilinear', name="Resize")(x)
    x = DepthwiseNormalization([91.4953, 103.8827, 131.0912])(x) # Another custom layer

    x = Conv2D(
        64, (7, 7), use_bias=False, strides=(2, 2), padding='same',
        name='conv1/7x7_s2')(x)
```

### Here's the error in its full glory

```
venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:742:0: note: see current operation: %1 = "tf.ReverseV2"(%arg0, %outputs_0) {device = ""} : (tensor<1x?x?x3x!tf.quint8>, tensor<1xi32>) -> tensor<1x?x?x3xui8>
```

```
error: 'tf.ReverseV2' op operand #0 must be tensor of bfloat16 type or 16-bit float or 32-bit float or 64-bit float or 1-bit signless integer or 16-bit signless integer or 32-bit signless integer or 64-bit signless integer or 8-bit signless integer or complex type with 64-bit float elements or complex type with 32-bit float elements or TensorFlow string type or 16-bit unsigned integer or 8-bit unsigned integer values, but got 'tensor<1x?x?x3x!tf.quint8>'
```

### Here are my custom layers, although I don't think this is the problem

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer import Layer
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops
import tensorflow as tf

class ChannelReversal(Layer):
    """Image color channel reversal layer (e.g. RGB -> BGR)."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(ChannelReversal, self).__init__()

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.reverse(inputs, axis=tf.constant([3]), name="channel_reversal")
        # return inputs[..., ::-1]


class DepthwiseNormalization(Layer):
    """Channel specific normalisation"""

    def __init__(self, mean=[0,0,0], stddev=[1.,1.,1.]):
        super(DepthwiseNormalization, self).__init__()
        self.mean = tf.broadcast_to(mean, [224,224,3])
        self.stddev = tf.broadcast_to(stddev, [224,224,3])   

    def call(self, inputs):
        if inputs.dtype != K.floatx():
            inputs = math_ops.cast(inputs, K.floatx())

        return (inputs - self.mean) / self.stddev
```

---

I was able to fix it by **removing** `dtype` argument in `input = Input(shape=input_shape, batch_size=1, dtype="uint8")`, but then the model expects Float32, which is brings an **issue** when using it in TensorFlow Lite.

Comment: `tf.quint8` seems to show that you are qunatizing your tflite model. Is that the case?

Comment: Nope, I'm not trying to do any quantization

Comment: By the way, if anyone is looking at my code in the future, we actually split up the preprocessing from the rest of the model (Conv2D), so we only need to run `allocateTensors` on a smaller model, which is much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround is to just use float32 in the model. This does mean I cast the input before passing it into the model, but this can be done by the TensorFlow lite support library. It looks like this might be a bug in the conversion to TensorFlow Lite.

`TensorBuffer imageBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFrom(image.getTensorBuffer(), DataType.FLOAT32);` will automatically cast it if the data type of image doesn't match FLOAT32.